# Enable show-battery-percentage systemwide

Tags: gnome, battery

How can I enable the battery percentage for my entire system?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage true
```

Only works for one profile at a time.

I checked on **/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas** but I couldn't find anything.